# Matching TinyMCE editor and initial textarea for smooth transition

Tags: tinymce

When the page first loads, it takes a few seconds for Tiny editor to replace the target textarea, and the delay is more noticeable when the editor's size doesn't perfectly match the original textarea whose size may vary as the textarea width changes based on the browser width given the responsive layout. What are some of the common approaches to address this issue? Thanks.